# Error 'dynamic module does not define module export function' while importing cythonized code

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, cythonize

I have been trying to import .pyd file but every time the error keeps comming:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_myfile)
```

Researching for may hours through many post, I installed Visual Code, Added environment variable, added MinGw, tried many different parametes for setup.py.
I found on some post that the cython version for python was infliction so i even installed form the source code of cython to remove any version dependencies.
Still no difference is coming.

I have read through posts reading to change/add distutils.cfg(setting to mingw:: Didnt work) and almost each and every post on most of forums. And also gcc compiler[This gives me another bunch of errors]

O.S. -- Windows 10

Python -- 3.7.2

[MSVC, cython, mingw are installed]

Setup.py::

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
directives = {'linetrace': False, 'language_level': 3}
setup(ext_modules = cythonize('myfile.pyx'))
```

myfile.pyx OR myfile.py::
[I am just using a simple Hello world as a test, the real file is too big]

These are the different Flow that is tried:

1)
`cython -3 myfile.py
   cythonize -a -i myfile.py`

2)`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

Also is am changing the name on outputfile by removing the .cp37-win32 part

Comment: Is *setup.py* the only source code required? What about *myfile.pyx*?

Comment: @CristiFati I have mentioned  that the myfile,pyx contains print("Hello world")

Comment: Aaa, OK I missed that part, but it wasn't specific anyway (I didn't work with *Cython* yet - just installed it). Do not remove the *.cp37-win32* part. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @CristiFati when i try to import it gives an error that -win32 is wrong atrribute or something

Comment: I was able to successfully build (via *setup.py*) and run your example.

Comment: @cristifati Mine is not ruunniing for god knows why